# Sophisticated HTML5 Image Map?

Tags: image, html, menu, hover, clickable

I have an image of a living room, which I'm turning into a menu for a new site I'm working on.  The idea is that you can click on certain items in the room, like a chair, desk, couch, etc and get taken to the desired page.  I'm wondering if there is a clever way of doing this.  Since the items are not simple shapes, I don't want to use a standard image map.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: You can ease the pain with an image map generator. Other than that, all I can think of is :gasp:... Flash. Maybe something can be done with `<canvas>`?

Comment: Yeah, it would be waaaaaaaaaay easier to do this in Flash, but I'm trying to get away from Flash and into HTML5...
Can you suggest an image map generator?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering because a Google search brought me here...

Because you asked for a tool:

GIMP Has a really good Image map creation function.

Open your image in GIMP and select Filters > Web > ImageMap

From there you can create image maps by drawing on the image. Saving will generate HTML you can then tailor to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This tool looks to be a solid image mapper: http://www.image-maps.com/
I'd suggest doing this with a canvas and SVG's, it would make this quite a bit easier, and more professional.

Answer (score 0):

As Korvin mentioned, doing this in SVG is probably the easiest option, because you can attach events to objects in SVG rather than having to manually specify a particular area in which to listen for events.

If you go this route, I recommend using the RaphaelJS library which has a nice syntax and the advantage of working in IE pre version 9. Here's a demo which, although it uses onmouseover instead of onclick, it might be close to what you're trying to achieve:

http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html